# GeoNetwork How to clone ISO19115-3.2018 schema plugin to generate profile

Tags: geonetwork

I need to generate a schema plugin for an ISO19115-3 profile, GeoNetwork `4.2.6-SNAPSHOT`, building from source, so I want to have the plugin in the source code. I tried setting it up following  instructions at https://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/4.0.x/en/customizing-application/implementing-a-schema-plugin.html.

I copied the `core-geonetwork\schemas\iso19115-3.2018` directory to `core-geonetwork\schemas` and renamed to `iso19115-3.DDE`, and added what seems to be the appropriate registrations in `geonetwork\schemas\pom.xml`, and `web/pom.xml`. I also went through `schemas\iso19115-3.DDE` folder and replaced `.2018` with `.DDE` where it seemed appropriate.

Tried `mvn process resources` and got this error:

```
[WARNING] The POM for org.geonetwork-opensource.schemas:gn-schema-iso19115-
3.DDE:zip:4.2.6-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
```

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-
plugin:3.1.2:unpack (unpack-schemas) on project gn-web-app: Unable to find/resolve artifact.: 
The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.geonetwork-opensource.schemas:gn-
schema-iso19115-3.DDE:zip:4.2.6-SNAPSHOT (absent): Could not find artifact 
org.geonetwork-opensource.schemas:gn-schema-iso19115-3.DDE:zip:4.2.6-SNAPSHOT in 
osgeo-snapshot (https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/snapshot/)
```

It looks like `mvn process-resources` is trying to download stuff from **https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/snapshot/org/geonetwork-opensource/schemas/**gn-schema-iso19115-3.DDE/4.2.6-SNAPSHOT/, but of course there's nothing there. Looks for `maven-metadata.xml`, then a pom, then a zip... and fails.

My reading of the `pom.xml` in my new schema directory is that is should create the `.zip` file in my local file system.

Any suggestions on how to get the build to work with the cloned schema plugin?

Comment: Maybe you could take a look at [iso19139.ca.HNAP](https://github.com/metadata101/iso19139.ca.HNAP) metadata schema and check how it's done there.

Comment: @juanluisrp  that profile is based on Geonetwork 3.1.2. Would the same procedure work with GN 4.2.6,  or am I better off using the ISO19115-3.2018 profile in metadata101 and GN 3.1.2?

Comment: There is a [4.2.x](https://github.com/metadata101/iso19139.ca.HNAP/tree/4.2.x) branch too.

Comment: I removed the gn-schema-iso19115-3.DDE-4.2.6-SNAPSHOTj.jar, ....zip, and ...-tests.jar and ran a full build (mvn package install -DskipTests), and the build was successful this time.  

The build took 13 hours-- is that normal?  Is there some way to speed it up?  (WSL Ubuntu 22 on Windows 11).

Comment: No, that isn't normal. Maybe you could try to exclude your sources directory from anti-virus analysis/windows defender.